# Передача частичного шаблона Flask(не работает)

Tags: flask

Нужно в appliation.html передать частичный шаблон index.html, но он не передается

application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'application.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello from index.html</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Структура

```
-app
 --templates
   ---application.html
   ---index.html
 -app.py
```

При переходе localhost:5000 вижу пустую страницу. Делаю по документации. В чем проблема?

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('application.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: А что у вас в route?

Comment: @Axenow, обновил

Comment: Попробуйте index.html отрисовать?

Comment: @Axenow, что значит отрисовать?

Comment: В render_template поменять app.html на index.html

Comment: @Axenow, спасибо большое, помогло